# Labirinto em prolog

Tags: prolog

Sou grande entusiasta da programação e estou com um pequeno problema que não consigo  pensar em mais nada.

A situação ser a seguinte: me propus a fazer um programa em *Prolog* que seja capaz se sair de um labirinto.

Já pesquisei muito na internet, porém não obtive muito sucesso, gostaria de alguma indicação de material ou dica para me levar a solução. Segue oque eu conseguir retirar do material que eu li:

```
start:-
      Li=1,
      Ci=1,
      Lf=6,
      Cf=8,
      lab(La),
      imprime(La),
      tenta(Li, Ci, Lf, Cf, La).

  lab(La):-
      La =(" ############",
           " #i         #",
           " # # # #### #",
           " #   # # #  #",
           " # # #   # ##",
           " # # # ######",
           " #   #  #f  #",
           " # #### ### #",
           " # #      # #",
           " # ###### # #",
           " #   #      #",
           " ############",

  tenta(Li, Ci, Lf, Cf, La):-
      tentaright().

  tenta(Li, Ci, Lf, Cf, La):-
      tentadown().

  tenta(Li, Ci, Lf, Cf, La):-
      tentaleft().

  tenta(Li, Ci, Lf, Cf, La):-
      tentaup().

  resolve():-
      tenta(Li, Ci, Lf, Cf, La),
      resolve().
```

PS: A indentação pode estar meio estranha, mas é porque meu ambiente de desenvolvimento tem numeração nas laterais e retirei aqui para ficar mais estético para postar.

Comment: Eu posso mudar a entrada?

Comment: fique a vontade

Comment: olá, você conseguiu resolver o problema depois? se sim, acho que seria interessante postar como resposta :)